# Updating errors in react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

So I created a custom input wrapper that takes in a couple of props from react-hook-form.

This is my text input

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const {
  register, 
  formState: { 
    errors 
  },
} = useForm();

<TextInput
  id={'password'}
  errors={errors}
  register={register}
  options={{
    minLength: {
      message: 'Please pick password longer than 8 characters',
      value:   8,
    },
    required: 'Password is required',
  }}
  type={"password"}
  placeholder={'Enter password'}
/>
```

In my component, I pass in these props and I try to display an error message if any of the conditions from options aren't met.

```
<div>
  <input
    error={errors[id] ? true : false}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type={type}
    {...register(id, options)}
  />
  {
    errors[id] &&
      <div>
        { errors[id].message }
      </div>
  }
</div>
```

The errors only show up when I have submitted the previous form and updated the text field, how do I get them to show up on submit?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the structure of your form,
but you can do something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const TextInput = ({errors, placeholder, type, id, register, options}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        // error={errors[id] ? true : false}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        {...register(id, options)}
      />
      {
        errors[id] &&
          <div>
            { errors[id].message }
          </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const {
    register, 
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { 
      errors 
    }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextInput
          id={'password'}
          errors={errors}
          register={register}
          options={{
            minLength: {
              message: 'Please pick password longer than 8 characters',
              value:   8,
            },
            required: 'Password is required',
          }}
          type={"password"}
          placeholder={'Enter password'}
        />
        <button>submit</button>
      </form>
    
  )
  
}
```

Here is a [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-smoke-qlfr5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Note: 
If your form is nested, you can use `useformcontext` 
you can read about it in the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext)